# Compare string within list of string using Ignore Symbol without foreach

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare a string within a list of string where I would like to use "IgnoreSymbols" compare option. Is there a way without "foreach" of list of string?

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string> { "Hello [T]", "XYA" };
string str = "Hello (T)";

var Y = String.Compare(str, lstString.Any(e => e.ToString()), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);

if (Y == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ, in general you are close with your idea, you just need to switch `Any` with `String.Compare`.

Like this:

```
var y = lstString.Any(e => string.Compare(str, e, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you want to know if the list contains a string that's equal to the search string (`str`), ignoring symbols.
You can use `Any`:

```
var lstString = new List<string> { "Hello [T]", "XYA" };
var str = "Hello (T)";

var Y = lstString.Any(s => String.Compare(s, str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0);

if (Y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? You can use projection and do whatever you want.

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string> { "Hello [T]", "XYA" };
string str = "Hello (T)";

var Y = lstString.Select(e => String.Compare(str, e, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols));

if (Y.Contains(0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
}
```

Or

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string> { "Hello [T]", "XYA" };
string str = "Hello (T)";

var Y = lstString.Any(e => String.Compare(str, e, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0);

if (Y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
}
```

Edited with @Bojan B suggestion :) thanks :)

Comment: Instead of using `Select` and then `Any` in the end, you can use Any directly on the list, it improves the readability a bit and the performance also (I think). But both options return the correct result

Comment: thanks @BojanB :) edited. I usually use R# that notifies me about this, but since I was using [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) I was on my own until you showed up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
var result = lstString.Any(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "").Equals(Regex.Replace(str, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")));
if(result) 
{
  // Write code here
}
```

But looking in detail I think using `foreach` or writing will result in same execution time if you are breaking from `foreach` loop.